# Add style of Text after creation

Tags: flutter

The project uses the `Text` widget to render text. There is an additional requirement that the style of the text changes if some condition evaluates to true. That is make the text bold or increase the font size. Is it possible to change the style of the text?

We were using the `Stepper` component. Now this needs to be replaced with our own custom Stepper widget. Is there a way to switch to the `CustomStepper`?

```
Stepper(
    currentStep: _step,
    steps: <Step>[
      Step(
        title: Text('Step 1'),
        content: Text('Step 1 body'),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text('Step 2'),
        content: Text('Step 2 body'),
      ),
    ],
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can check for conditions in style parameter and according to the condition you can change the TextStyle.

Answer (score 2):

```
Text("something",style:isBold?_boldTextStyle:_normalTextStyle);
```

if `isBold` is updated just call setState, so widget rebuilds meeting the condition

Answer (score 0):

A Text is a widget in flutter and widget are nested inside each other to the root of the widget tree and are redrawn every time their build function is called by the framework.
So changing a property like fontSize inside style isn't any different from changing the text shown inside the Text widget for example. Flutter draws it with the values you have provided.

So if let's assume this is the state of the StatefulWidget that renders your Text widget. You can easily increase the fontSize like this:

You can learn more about how flutter renders Widgets in here:
[Flutter architectural overview](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview)
[Introduction to widgets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro)

```
class _SizeIncreasingTextPageState extends State<SizeIncreasingTextPage> {
  double _fontSize = 13;

  void _increaseFontSize() {
    setState(() {
      _fontSize++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text(
        "This will get bigger!",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: _fontSize),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _increaseFontSize,
        tooltip: 'Bigger!',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```